# Is it possible to accept answers in closed questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions, accepted-answer

Out of curiosity (since I don't have any closed questions), is it possible to accept answers on closed questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes

> Yes, you can still accept it, and answers can still be voted on by
> everyone. Other users can also vote on your question.
>
> Only [locking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) prevents these actions.

Source: [Can an answer of a closed question be accepted? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91830/267099)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible (see @DavidPostill's answer) and moreover, it happens quite often. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1275759/accepted-answers-after-closing-a-question) are over 2,500 cases where a Super User question was closed and an answer was accepted next day or even later.